# Count of raster cells as variable in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, raster, modelbuilder

I want to use a cell count of an integer raster as a variable in Arcgis 10 ModelBuilder (and later in a python script), but can't seem to find how to access this information.

Is there a (python) function that will return a cell count for a particular value? 
eg. something like

```
count([raster], value)?
```

Or how do I access the count column for a particular value in the raster table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to access it by reading the attribute table (assuming you have one; if you don't there is also a python function to create one).

```
# loop through attribute table    
Rows = ARCPY.SearchCursor( shapefile ) 

SomeValue = 'Count' # or some other column header name
for row in Rows:
    val = row.getValue( SomeValue ) 
    print val
```

Comment: To build the raster attribute table: arcpy.BuildRasterAttributeTable_management("c:/data/image.tif", "Overwrite")

Comment: Thanks, to get counts for a particular value in the raster table I used this in the for loop:
`val = row.getValue('Value')`
`count = row.getValue('Count')`
    `if val==1:`
        `return count`
getValue worked with single quotes, but row.Value also worked.

Comment: great - I'll clarify my answer to explain what I meant by `SomeValue`; I choose `print` just to illustrate the result; `return` is better of course but you need to create a function.